# Porting from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 5.0 System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase functionality in .NET 5.0?

Tags: .net-5, .net-4.8

I'm porting an application from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 5.0.  Is there there a way to bring the functionality of System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase to .NET 5.0?  Are there any alternatives that could replace ServiceBase?  Any workarounds?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a Windows service from .Net Core 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56638847/how-to-make-a-windows-service-from-net-core-3)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ServiceBase` is available in the NuGet package [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController/). Visual Studio should suggest to install that package if you press Ctrl+. while the cursor is on the `ServiceBase` class name in the code editor.

If you create a new service you should think about switching to worker services (it has its own project template), see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host). To run those worker services as a Windows service you'd then use the [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices) package. (That package also uses `ServiceBase` internally.)

Comment: I think that does answer my question.  Thank you.

Comment: @MagicMic Please mark the answer as accepted to indicate that the question is resolved.